# In a KeyEvent handler, I want to know the Node under the cursor

Tags: javafx

My code stops at a breakpoint when I type a certain character, so that I can inspect things in the debugger.  (I use an event filter to do this.)

It would be nice to be able to inspect the `Node` that was under the cursor when I typed the character.

I can’t see how to do this.

Apparently I can use `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()` to get the cursor x,y, but I can’t see how to go from x,y to the frontmost intersecting `Node`.  I suppose I could maintain a set of all nodes and go through them brute-force, but it seems to me there must be a more elegant solution.

UPDATE

At this question, [JavaFX 2.2 get node at coordinates (visual tree hit testing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420569/javafx-2-2-get-node-at-coordinates-visual-tree-hit-testing), I found an FX bug report,
[FX should provide a Parent.pick() routine](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8091684), which led to another bug report, [Make impl_pickNode public.](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8102426), which led to this StackOverflow answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16279603/1390116

That trick, however seems to work only when already in a `MouseEvent` dragged handler.  I don't see how that will get me what I need from a `KeyEvent` handler.

Comment: Possible duplicate [JavaFX 2.2 get node at coordinates (visual tree hit testing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420569/javafx-2-2-get-node-at-coordinates-visual-tree-hit-testing)